# How to map a rather complex Business Process like Order to Cash to Corda Flow(s)

Tags: corda, corda-flow

Imagine a real world business process which can take weeks shall be mapped to single or multiple Corda Flows. As long living flows have impact of SW lifecycle (see   https://docs.corda.net/upgrading-cordapps.html#flow-drains) I wonder if there are design guidelines for flows regarding time to life or other aspects like versioning/compatibility/dependencies to sub-flows/ ...).

Comment: Can you describe the process in more detail? It may be possible to split it into multiple smaller flows.

Comment: The complete process e.g. : http://nazrinrizal.blogspot.com/2012/01/sap-erp-overview.html includes main "spaces": ordering, production, shipping and payment. Each space is interconnected with others and can again be split into smaller steps like: Shipment Notification -> GoodsIssued -> GoodsReceived -> Quality Check ...

Answer (score 0):

You would typically model each document to states i.e `SalesOrder, Goods, Delivery, Bill`

Then for each action, it's just a flow within Corda.i.e `ApproveSalesOrderFlow, IssueGoodsFlow, ReceiveGoodsFlow, FulfillShipmentFlow, SettleBillFlow etc.`

Because some process may takes weeks, you'll need to model lifecycle/status in the states. i.e `SalesOrder` may have lifecycle such as `ISSUED, APPROVED, DELIVERED, PAID`. Upon each action (flow), you're transitioning the state from an initial status to its respective new statuses to track its lifecycle. i.e an `ApproveSalesOrderFlow` may move the state from `ISSUED` to `APPROVED`, and you would track the `lastApprovedDate, durationOfSLA, etc` as fields in the state.